# After transcoding using ffmpeg, I found audio bitrate is not the value I expected

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, transcoding, bitrate

I used ffmpeg to transcode some files into new format and with certain parameters. After transcoding, I found some output file's metadata is not what I expected, the output value is not the same with I set in the cmd line.

Before transcoding I check the media info of the inputfile:

```
ffmpeg -i dz2015082000010.mpg
```

> ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
>   built with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC) 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
>   configuration: --enable-static --enable-memalign-hack --enable-libx264
>   --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib --enable-debug=3 --disable-optimizations --enable-nonfree --enable-libmp3lame     libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101     libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101     libavformat    57. 56.101 /
>   57. 56.101     libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100     libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100     libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100     libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100     libpostproc    54.  1.100 /
>   54.  1.100   Input #0, mpeg, from 'dz2015082000010.mpg':     Duration: 00:01:49.30, start: 0.685389, bitrate: 15723 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, top first),   1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr,
>   90k tbn, 50 tbc
>       Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 384 kb/s   At least one output file must be specified

Next, transcoding with the cmd line:

```
ffmpeg -i dz2015082000010.mpg -vcodec libx264 -b:v 4000k -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -g 25  -vprofile main -acodec aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -y output.ts
```

After transcoding, I check the media info of the output file:

```
ffmpeg -i output.ts
```

> ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers     built with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC) 20140911 (Red Hat
>   4.8.3-9)      configuration: --enable-static --enable-memalign-hack --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib --enable-debug=3 --disable-optimizations --enable-nonfree --enable-libmp3lame      libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101      libavcodec     57. 64.101
>   / 57. 64.101      libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
>   libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100      libavfilter     6. 65.100
>   /  6. 65.100      libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
>   libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100      libpostproc    54.  1.100
>   / 54.  1.100    Input #0, mpegts, from 'full-2.ts':      Duration:
>   00:01:49.30, start: 1.456778, bitrate: 4455 kb/s      Program 1
>       Metadata:
>         service_name    : Service01
>         service_provider: FFmpeg
>       Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr,
>   90k tbn, 50 tbc
>       Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 4 kb/s    At least one output file must be
>   specified

I don't know why the audio bitrate is changed to 4 kb/s after transcoding, I set the value with -b:a 128k before, anybody can help me?  BTW, the output file sounds all right.

Answer (score 0):

The native encoder won't waste bits on silent portions. And it doesn't do strict CBR. If you really need an output to be around the target bitrate, you can mix in a very low level of noise.